# Calling a function from Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function that takes in a set of numbers and returns a computed value. When I try to call it from `ngAfterViewInit`

When I do I get an error that is undefined.

How do I create a function in angular 2 that can be fired from `ngAfterViewInit`?

the is after the `ngOnInit()`

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.gridW = document.getElementById('grid').offsetWidth;

    console.log(getColWidth(10,8,800));
     
  }

  getColWidth(gutW,colN,gridW) {
    let gutWTotal = gutW*(colN-1);
    let gridWResult = gridW - gutWTotal;
    let colW = gridWResult/colN;

    return Math.floor(colW);
  }
```

error: `ERROR ReferenceError: getColWidth is not defined`

Comment: It would seem like the pertinent question is not how you do it, but why is your value `undefined`?

Comment: when I call the function I get an error that the function is undefined.

Comment: Could you provide some code.?

Comment: @FranklinPious added!

Comment: @Muirik sorry, "not defined" not "undefined"

Comment: `this.getColWidth`

Comment: Yup, from within a life cycle hook you'd want to do `this.getColWidth`. You define it elsewhere, then call it here with `this`.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you provide this as answer so I can select it and upvote?

Comment: no worries. i think this should be closed due to being a simple typographic error